# Read & Update Cookies in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, cookies

I'm trying to manage Cookies and, so far, I've wasted days on this problem, and in frustration, am asking here in vain hope that someone out there knows the REAL solution.

So far I've read about and tried examples for:

Response / Request

HttpResponse / HttpRequest

I've seen that you need to Import System.Net.UI.Page, but that doesn't exist in VB.NET

Nothing works.

I've searched through the References/Namespaces and can't find ANYTHING that will enable the Cookie Request/Response functionality.

Please note that this is VB.NET not ASP.NET, I don't want any solutions that are specific to ASP.NET unless I can import something like the ASP Namespace.

Comment: what cookies do you want to manage? There are they come from?

Comment: Website Cookies. Added by Websites.

Comment: Your comment was also not helpful. It's obvious that cookies do not come from the street or space. You should tell us which cookies do you want to manage. Did you use webbrowser control, or maybe used httpwebrequest or simply want to use IE or firefox cookies. You have to tell us what does manage mean in your case. Read from where? Update what?

Comment: I've told you. I want to manage Cookies that are created by Websites. I'm using the WebBrowser control (IE).  Firefox and IE do not create cookies, the Websites you load into the browsers create the cookies.  I need to be able to read (Request) cookies created by a specific domain, and expire/remove (Response) them.  You obviously do not understand Cookies, so maybe you are not the right person to be responding to my query.

Comment: lol ok, I've always liked offensive newbies. I've already answered similar questions, so you can go through my answers and if you understand the subject a little, you will probably find your solution. good luck

Comment: I'm not a newbie. Nor am I being offensive. I'm trying to give you the information you request, but we are obviously at cross purposes here.  I've read ALL the posts on cookies, some of them may even have been yours, but none of them work for VB.NET. This is the reason I'm asking this question. I'd even be happy to know that managing cookies is not possible in VB.NET, rather than continuing to waste my time attempting the impossible.